# Zedgraph zoom does not work properly on some Systems

Tags: c#, winforms, retina-display, zedgraph, highdpi

I observed something interesting the other day and I wanted to know whether anyone has a clue why this is happening and also how one could fix this issue.
It appears that the zooming using Zedgraph has issues on some systems leading to the zoom selection box being off from where the mouse position would be (see screenshot)

I think it has something todo with high DPI screens but I am not sure since my sample size is quite small. Once it happened on a Microsoft Surface 3 pro and the other time on a Lenovo Y50-70 (both running windows 8.1).

I also tested other software tools where I knew that they also use Zedgraph in order to see whether I am doing something wrong but the effect was exactly the same.
Any ideas?

[image: The dashed selection box is not where my mouse cursor is selecting it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue being related to the DPI settings of the screen in windows.
If you select anything else but 100%, ZedGraph (5.1.5) will not be able to calculate the zoom box correct. This issue has been fixed in later versions of ZedGraph (>= 5.1.7).

[image: From Windows 8.1]

Comment: this post is ages old, but where did you find 5.1.7?